# How do I update a variable with the position my loop is currently referencing?

Tags: python

I have a list of inputs and I am using a for loop to search through each of the value to find the highest temperature and at what position in the list that is.

I have written the code out in full except I do not know what I would put to update the best_position with the current position my loop is looking at.

```
    # set best_position to position
    best_position =
```

This is where I am struggling.

```
# initialise the input with a non-empty list - Do NOT change the next line
temperatures = [4.7, 3, 4.8]
# set best_position to 0
best_position = 0
maxtemp = temperatures[0]
# for each position from 1 to length of list – 1:
for i in temperatures:
    # if the item at position is better than the item at best_position: 
    if maxtemp<i:
        maxtemp = i
        # set best_position to position
        best_position =
# print best_position
print(best_position, ": 00")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `enumerate` function:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

```
# initialise the input with a non-empty list - Do NOT change the next line
temperatures = [4.7, 3, 4.8]
# set best_position to 0
best_position = 0
maxtemp = temperatures[0]
# for each position from 1 to length of list – 1:
for pos, t in enumerate(temperatures):
    # if the item at position is better than the item at best_position: 
    if maxtemp<t:
        maxtemp = t
        # set best_position to position
        best_position = pos
# print best_position
print(best_position, ": 00")
```

Alternatively, you can just do:

```
max_temp = max(temperatures)
best_pos = temperatures.index(max_temp)
print(best_pos, ": 00")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick to the `for` loop you can use `enumerate` as explained in @abdusco 's answer. Alternatively, you can use Python's power and do a nice built-in one-liner:

```py
print(max(range(len(temperatures)), key=lambda i: temperatures[i]), ": 00")
```

and this will be used as:

```py
>>> temperatures = [4.7, 3, 4.8]
>>> print(max(range(len(temperatures)), key=lambda i: temperatures[i]), ": 00")
2 : 00
```

To break it down:

- the `max` function returns the maximum between the indices of the list.
- but instead of comparing them by value, it compares by the value at that index in the list